# custom holo style progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want to create custom progress bar in android which is as follows

[image]

But i `don't want to use any external library` like `actionbarsherlock` for that so how can i create it using xml layouts and all. i am using android 2.3.3 version.

More over i tried to copy some styles , drawable images from `HoloEveryWhere` from this [link](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/HoloDemo/res/layout-v4/main.xml)
but i am not getting expected result. please look below. its a constantly moving bar.

[image]

i used following code

```
   <ProgressBar
                style="@style/ProgressBarHolo.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:progress="25" />
```

and in style

```
<item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_holo_dark</item>
<item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the definitions of "progress_horizontal_holo_dark" and "progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo". Here are the files: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/HoloEverywhereLib/res/drawable/progress_horizontal_holo_dark.xml and https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/HoloEverywhereLib/res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo.xml

Don't forget to copy the assets mentioned in above two files too.

Then you will see the progress bar shown in your second image.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is not a `progressBar` but a `seekBar`. The drawables you copied are the drawables of the holo progress bar, but the one you see is an indeterminate progressBar. That's why it's a constantly moving bar.

Just `setIndeterminate="false"` and set the progress, max etc and you will have a holo determinate `progressBar`.

But the first image you posted is a seek bar =) => link [HERE](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/seek-bars.html)